# SSAS dimension intersection of attribute values

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

Normally dimension values in a cube are distinct and selecting multiple values means: "give me all rows with either of the values (union)". Instead of this I want the intersection, so only the rows which have all values selected. How do I model this in microsoft analysis services?

So example 1 would be a dimension Store, with a value "store A" linking to multiple related values T1 in a different dimension, and "store B" linking to T1 and T2 and lastly "store C" linking to no values.

What I'm looking for is that selecting T1 gives me store A and B, and selecting T1 and T2 only gives me B, not A.

Comment: Can you illuminate this with an example?   How can a fact have two values for the same dimension? Are you looking for a CROSSJOIN?

Comment: Updated with example, I started out with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385513/ssas-one-to-many-dimensional-relationship. It works but only as union, not as intersection.

Comment: Your example sounds more OLTP than OLAP.  Can you re-state your example in terms of facts and dimensions?   What is value T1?   A dimension value?   A measure value?   Are you sure you should be using a cube at all?   Your goal doesn't sound suited to SSAS.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the clarification notes, see my revised question and the link. That is how I have modelled the store can have one to many values for T.

Comment: You don't link dimensions to other dimensions in SSAS.  You either combine them into one hierarchical dimension, or you let them link individually to the fact table.